# Generic type container in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I want to create a generic type container in Java, using an interface like this:

```
public interface GenericDataContainer<T>
```

I want classes that'll implement this interface to have an underlying structure to hold data of type `T`. However, I also want to keep track of who a piece of data was added by. In the `GenericDataContainer` interface, a method to add an object to the container might have a declaration like this:

```
public void put(String added_by, T obj);
```

I am just getting started with generics, and also Java in general, so I'm not sure what the best way to go about this would be.

Let's say I have a structure, like a `HashMap` that keeps track of what users I have, and let's say I identify users by their `name` `String`. How would I go about associating a `T` object inside my container to the `String` of the user who added it?

Would I wrap the object into a wrapper class that has two members:

```
T obj;
String added_by;
```

or is there a better way?

Let's say I also want to be able to allow certain users to access the object, not just the owner; could I just add an array of `String`s to such wrapper object to keep track of users who were granted access?

This is what the whole interface specification is like (please don't critique it: I have no control over the specification)

```
public interface SecureDataContainer<T>{
    public void createUser(String id, String passw);
    
    // number of elements added by owner
    public int getSize(String owner, String passw);
    
    public boolean put(String owner, String passw, T data);

    public T get(String owner, String passw, T data);

    public T remove(String owner, String passw, T data);
    
    public void copy(String owner, String passw, T data);
    
    // enable another user to access the object
    public void share(String owner, String passw, String other, T data);

    public Iterator<T>getIterator(String owner, String passw);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. You only use "_" in SOME_CONSTANT, for anything else, you use lowerCamelCase, or UpperCamelCase (class/interface/... names start upper case, anything else lower case).

Comment: Can the same person add multiple objects to your collection? 

If so, maybe you're looking for a Map<String, List<T>>. This is a pretty common compound data type, and if you're willing to use a third party library, I recommend guava's multimap for this purpose. https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: The best way to begin to answer the questions you have, is to complete the interface definition. So far, you have a `put()` method for adding an object and registering who did the add. Next very important method(s) for you to define, are the methods for querying the container about its content. What should the method(s) be? Can you get all objects added by some specific user? Or what?

Comment: @Andreas, I have updated my post with the whole interface specification in my post

Answer (score 2):

What you outlined makes sense, you could do something like:

```
public class OwnedData<T> {
  private final OwnerId owner;
  private final T data;

  // constructor taking owner/data ... getters maybe

}
```

(Note: it makes more sense to have a distinct type that denotes Owners, you might have two different users named "Carl", so better prepare yourself to be not rely just on a String name to identify owners)

But yes, that would be one way to go about this. Of course, you then have to think to correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for that class, to ensure that objects can be clearly distinguished.

Yet, in the real world, things are of course much more complicated. Permission models are complicated. You have to think not only about users, but also about "roles". Or groups of users. Or some data being read-only, some data being read/writeable.

In other words: there are many different requirements that a permission system *might* have to fulfil. Therefore we can't tell you what is *best for you*, as nobody here knows your specific requirements!

Comment: Thank you! If I were to declare a `Vector` of these `OwnedData` objects, what would the declaration be like? `Vector<OwnedData<T>>`?

Comment: For example. But rather learn about Collections, like List/ArrayList. Vector is so 2005.

Comment: I understand that. I will learn about those on my own, but my lecturer still seems to endorse the use of Vectors, so I kinda have to go along with that

Comment: If you are up to that: consider to challenge your instructor. Ask him why you should spend energy to learn something that is really outdated, and not to be found in current day java code.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I have a structure, like a HashMap that keeps track of what
> users I have, and let's say I identify users by their name String. How
> would I go about associating a T object inside my container to the
> String of the user who added it?

What's wrong with :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface GenericDataContainer<T> {
    public void put(String added_by, T obj);
}

class HashMapBasedContainer<T> implements GenericDataContainer<T> {

    //if this lives somewhere else, make sure it's accessible from here
    Map<String, T> mapper = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void put(String added_by, T obj) {
        this.mapper.put(added_by, obj);
    }
}
```

> Let's say I also want to be able to allow certain users to access the
> object, not just the owner; could I just add an array of Strings to
> such wrapper object to keep track of users who were granted access?

You could implement the interface again in a version that does exactly that.

Comment: The question in my post is about a school assignment (I'm actually working the project that was assigned last year for practice, it's not the one that'll actually be graded) that requires us to provide our own implementation of the interface. That is why I can't use the default one

Answer (score 0):

If a user can only ever add a single object to your collection, then a `Map<String, T>` would suffice.

Then your put method is literally just the built in `Map` put.
`myMap.put(ownerString, dataOfTypeT)`

If you want a single user to be able to add multiple data to your collection, then you want to create a `Map<String,List<T>>`.

Then your put method needs to create the list first if it doesn't already exist, otherwise it's the same.

```java
class MyContainer<T> {
   private Map<String, List<T>> backingMap = new HashMap<>();

   public void put(String userName, T data) {
     if (!map.containsKey(userName)) {
        map.put(userName, new ArrayList<>());
     }
     map.get(userName).add(data);
   }

   public List<T> getAllData(String userName) {
      if (!map.get(userName)) {
         // in my opinion it makes more sense to return empty list than null
         return List.of() 
      }
      // making a copy is a good idea so that the caller can't modify our list. 
      return List.copyOf(map.get(userName)) 

   }
}
```

If you are okay with using a third party library, [guava's ListMultimap](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) provides similar behavior.

Comment: Users can add more than one object. The reason I wouldn't want to do it the way you explained (of course you couldn't know about this because I didn't say it in my post) is that each user also has a password, and functions to add or remove an element from the collection also take in a password parameter to authenticate the user. Somewhere, I will need a structure (a `HashMap` maybe) that maps users to their password for comparison. I do realize this is not the ideal way to do it, but I gotta adhere to the assignment specifications